# ASQL statement for searching SSN number in a table that can have up to 4800 VARCHAR

Tags: db2, db2-zos

I am searching for SSN number that was indicated in a Table with 4800 varchar.

I tried

SSN_MSG Like ‘%[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%’

But it didn’t work. I need to check for the format of SSN which is  SSN 000-00-0000

Comment: This is for DB2 mainframe

Comment: Then why did you tag for MySQL?  What version of DB2 are you using?

Comment: That Is what i expected but as i tried it i received a message “No rows qualified”. But In my test table i did put SSN number such as “SSN should be123-45-6789”

Comment: Sorry this is my first time asking question in stackoverflow.

Comment: What version of DB2 are you using?

Comment: This is version 11 i guess

Comment: Then you might be able to use `REGEXP_LIKE` here.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read, DB2 version 11 should support [`REGEXP_LIKE`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061494.html):

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(SSN_MSG, '[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}')
```

Comment: Db2 for LUW and DB2 for Z/OS are different products. [REGEXP_LIKE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_regexplike.html) function you mentioned is supported starting from V12 there.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein Well in this case maybe the OP would have to resort to using a user defined function.

Answer (score 0):

For earlier DB2 versions the [fn:matches](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/xml/src/tpc/db2z_fnmatches.html) function can be used, which allows the same regular expression.

```
with tab (str) as (
select '123-45-6789' from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all
select '123456789' from sysibm.sysdummy1
)
select str
from tab
where xmlcast(xmlquery('fn:matches($s, "[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}")' passing str as "s") as int)=1;

STR
-----------
123-45-6789
```